# Powershell to get SNMP settings

Tags: powershell, get, settings, snmp

I need to get SNMP information from the registry of remote servers using alternative credentials. To get the trap names I'm using this

```
$server =  "ServerName"
    $Reg = Get-WmiObject -List -Namespace root\default -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "StdRegProv"}
    $HKLM = 2147483650
    $TrapName = ($reg.EnumKey("$HKLM","SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration")).sNames
    $TrapName
```

What I need to get now is get the "Value data" from each $TrapName where the "Value name is 1" 
Could someone help. Thank you

Comment: See related question on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/579091/how-do-i-remotely-install-configure-and-maintain-snmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$reg has an EnumValues method, which enumerates the values for a given key. So you will invoke EnumValues for each member of the collection $TrapName. Then for each call to EnumValues look in the sNames collection to see contains a value with the name 1. When you find a $TrapName with the value of 1 you use a third method on $reg, GetDWORDValue/GetStringValue/etc. based on what the type of the value whose name is 1 is. (The object that EnumValues returns has a Types member that you can use to determine the value's type).

In Powershell you can see what methods and properties an object has by using get-member. For example: `$reg | get-member` will show you the various Get*Value methods, as well as the EnumKeys and EnumValues methods.